# Scrap JSON table using xpath in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm tring to scrap the table in https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2023/arts-humanities?&tab=indicators using R, the `rvest` package in particular. The table is dynamic. From what I've read, I could scrap it using this package and xpaths. I got the xpath using the Developer Tools from Chrome.

```
library(rvest)

webpage <- read_html("https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2023/arts-humanities?&page=34&tab=indicators")

links <- html_nodes(webpage, xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/main/section/div/section/section/div/div/article/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/section/div[4]/div")
```

This doesn't work, though. Another method I tried was this:

```
# include the installed library rvest
library(rvest)

# call the url
url <- "https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2023/arts-humanities?&tab=indicators"

# get the data
page <- read_html(url)

# filter the required data using xpath
rows <- html_nodes(page, xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/main/section/div/section/section/div/div/article/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/section/div[4]/div") %>% 
  html_text()

# print
rows
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be aware that the table content comes from a JSON, most often it means it's fetched by javascript and it's not included in the page source, i.e. it's not possible to extract table content with `rvest` by just using those same selectors and XPaths that are working in your javascript-enabled browser.

Rectangling that JSON into something similar to rendered table on the page could be achieved with something like this:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

"https://www.topuniversities.com/rankings/endpoint?nid=3846211&page=0&items_per_page=15&tab=indicators&region=&countries=&cities=&search=&star=&sort_by=&order_by=" %>% 
  fromJSON() %>% 
  pluck("score_nodes") %>% 
  # fromJSON() transforms scores into list of 5x4 data.frames
  # selecting relevant columns and pivoting wider turns those into 1x5 data.frames,
  # single row per parent data.frame row, `scores` will remain a nested column for now
  mutate(scores = map(scores, 
                      \(x) select(x, indicator_name, score) %>% 
                        pivot_wider(names_from = indicator_name, values_from = score))) %>% 
  select(title, region, country, city, overall_score, rank_display, scores) %>% 
  # extract all 5 score columns
  unnest(scores)
```

Result:

```r
#> # A tibble: 15 × 11
#>    title   region country city  overall_score rank_display `Academic Reputation`
#>    <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>         <chr>        <chr>                
#>  1 "Harva… North… United… Camb… 98.2          1            100                  
#>  2 "Unive… Europe United… Camb… 96.9          2            99.2                 
#>  3 "Unive… Europe United… Oxfo… 96.8          3            99.4                 
#>  4 "Stanf… North… United… Stan… 91.6          4            93.7                 
#>  5 "Unive… North… United… Berk… 91.5          5            95.4                 
#>  6 "Yale … North… United… New … 88.9          6            94.5                 
#>  7 "Colum… North… United… New … 88.6          =7           92.5                 
#>  8 "New Y… North… United… New … 88.6          =7           93.8                 
#>  9 "Unive… North… United… Los … 88.3          9            92.5                 
#> 10 "The U… Europe United… Edin… 87.8          10           92.2                 
#> 11 "UCL"   Europe United… Lond… 87            11           90.3                 
#> 12 "Massa… North… United… Camb… 86.6          12           86.3                 
#> 13 "Princ… North… United… Prin… 86            13           92.4                 
#> 14 "Unive… North… United… Chic… 85.9          14           93.3                 
#> 15 "Unive… North… Canada  Toro… 85.2          15           89                   
#> # ℹ 4 more variables: `Employer Reputation` <chr>, `Citations per Paper` <chr>,
#> #   `H-index Citations` <chr>, `International Research Network` <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note that the API call retuns just for first 15 records, feel free to adjust `items_per_page`parameter in URL.